# How to get editable categories from a MediaWiki page

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am trying to get all the editable categories from a page for a user script I am working on on Wikipedia.

What I am struggling is figuring out how to filter the uneditable categories from the editable categories.

Here is the code that is supposed to get the list of editable categories (so far):

```js
var categorylist = mw.config.get("wgCategories");
if (categorylist.length == 0) {
    ...
} else {
    $.get(mw.config.get("wgScriptPath") + "/api.php", {
        action: "parse",
        format: "json",
        page: mw.config.get("wgPageName"),
        prop: "wikitext"
    }).done(function(result) {
        var editablelist = result.parse.wikitext.match(/* some regex here */);
    })
}
```

I have been experimenting with RegExr to figure out what will match all the category links:  `/\[\[Category:.*\]\]/g`

[I do not want to match the spaces between category links, just the individual category links.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF6eX.png)

Is there an efficient way to match all the editable categories from the wikitext of a MediaWiki page?

Answer (score 0):

For not matching the spaces between category links, use the following regex:

```
\[\[Category:[^\[\]]*\]\]
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/eJa9AP/1) a demo.

`[^\[\]]` means "a character that is neither an open nor close squared brackets".

---

If you don't want to match neither the squared brackets nor eventual sortkeys, you will need a more complex regex:

```
(?<=\[\[)Category:[^\[\]|]*(?=(?:\|[^\[\]]*)?\]\])
```

Take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/eJa9AP/2) for a regex demo.

Now you are ensuring that the expression is preceded by two open squared brackets, followed by an optional sortkey (`\|[^\[\]]*`) and finaly by two closed squared brackets.

Every sub-expression contained within lookarounds (`(?<=X)` or `(?=X)`) is not captured.